# Why is greeting someone before praying compared to building a private altar?

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer, tractate-brachot, mizbeach-altar

Berachos 14a:

> אָמַר רַב: כָּל הַנּוֹתֵן שָׁלוֹם לַחֲבֵירוֹ קוֹדֶם שֶׁיִּתְפַּלֵּל כְּאִילּוּ עֲשָׂאוֹ בָּמָה. שֶׁנֶּאֱמַר: ״חִדְלוּ לָכֶם מִן הָאָדָם אֲשֶׁר נְשָׁמָה בְּאַפּוֹ כִּי בַמֶּה נֶחְשָׁב הוּא״. אַל תִּקְרֵי, ״בַּמֶּה״ אֶלָּא ״בָּמָה״.
>
> Rav said, "Whoever greets his friend before praying, it's as if he made him a private altar, as it says, 'Cease from you man, in whose nostrils there is breath, for how little [בַמֶּה] is he considered' – don't read it as 'for how little [בַמֶּה],' but rather, 'a private altar [בָּמָה].'"

What is this comparison, exactly? The case of a private altar is one who offers a karban to Hashem outside the Beis HaMikdash – but it's still being offered to Hashem. Here, he's neglecting Hashem and instead giving importance to someone else; should the comparison not be to idolatry, rather than to a private altar?

Comment: Cf. [*Sotah* 4b](https://www.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=18&daf=4b&format=text), where 'Ulla uses the same *d'rasha* to denounce people who are arrogant. Rashi over there says it indeed refers to a private altar of idolatry.

Comment: @Fred That's fascinating, thanks for the source. According to Rashi there, what's the difference between Ulla and R' Yochanan?

Comment: I don't think there's a fundamental difference between them, just that each formulation was more suitable to the accompanying *d'rasha*. Maybe you can *teitch* some subtle nuance of difference between them, though (worship idolatry vs. build an idolatrous altar).

Comment: This rule only makes sense if you know about Roman Salutatio https://www.thoughtco.com/ancient-roman-history-salutatio-112667 The greeting is not what you think it is.

Comment: @DoubleAA See the remark of the Rif, "והני מילי במשכים לפתחו אבל בשאינו משכים לפתחו שרי דתנן בפרקים שואל מפני הכבוד ומשיב שלום לכל אדם", specifying the problem is only going out of your way to greet someone at their home before prayers (though some *acharonim* extend this to going out of your way to greet someone even in a different part of the shul, see MB 89:9). Perhaps that might smack of some kind of subservience.

Comment: @DoubleAA Care to write it up as an answer?

Answer (score 1):

ArtScroll Brachos 14a2 note 18 explains this by comparing someone who is davening to someone who is in the process of bringing the karbonos on the mizbeach. One is worshiping Hashem in an improper manner. It is like building an altar to Hashem in one's back yard

> Our prayers are a substitute for the offering that were brought while
>   the Temple stood. Therefore, one who greets his fellow in the morning
>   before greeting Hashem through his prayers resembles one who goes to
>   bring offerings on a *bamah* and abandons the offerings of the Temple
>   Altar (*Maharsha*).

Comment: But...why? Why is the comparison to a Bamah and not to idolatry?

Comment: @DonielF Because one is not worshiping an idol. One is worshiping Hashem in an improper manner. It is like building an altar to Hashem in one's back yard.

Comment: How is greeting a friend worshiping Hashem improperly?

Comment: @DonielF The gemara says that it is like taking the offering out of the temple to put it on a bamah.

Comment: I know the Gemara says that, my entire question is on what grounds does the Gemara say that, what the comparison is exactly. Where do you address specifically how greeting a friend is comparable to offering it on a Bamah?

Comment: @DonielF The point that the gemara is making is that praying is like going to the bais hamikdash to serve Hashem. Thus, going to shul to daven is analogous to going to the bais hamikdash. Greeting someone when one is supposed to be davening is like leaving the bais hamikdash in the middle of the service. Since the bais hamikdash service is a korbon, it is therefore like walking out with the animal that was supposed to be put on the altar. When that is done, it is like putting it on a bama even though the bama is also meant to be for Hashem.

Comment: You’re still not answering the question. Why is that a Bama and not Avodah Zarah?

Comment: @DonielF because the person is still attempting to worship Hashem and not an idol. He is just doing it incorrectly.

Comment: But _how_ is he attempting to worship Hashem? You still haven’t answered that.

Comment: @DonielF The note in the Art Scroll gemara explains how this is considered. This is based on the *Maharsha*

Comment: And I fail to understand how this answers the question. To me the "therefore" is a non-sequitur.

Comment: @DonielF, I think the missing piece of information is that “Shalom” is one of Hashem’s names, not just a greeting. So, since one is not supposed to say Hashem’s name before davening they would be using Hashem’s name improperly by greeting with “Shalom”  (I believe I heard this in Rav Dovid Grossman’s daf yomi shiur through Talmud).