# Allowed to text someone a greeting before davening shacharis

Tags: shacharis-morning-prayer

Would it be permitted to text someone a greeting before shacharis, or would this be forbidden.  (The person you are texting is not in the same state/country that you are in.)

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya lbenson. Is there anything in particular motivating this question? Have you previously seen/heard that this might be forbidden? Have you seen/heard that other forms of communication are forbidden and you're wondering if this is the same? Remember, the more details you provide in your post the better the community can answer your question, and you have up to 30,000 characters to do so.

Comment: related: [morning activities before prayers](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/61339/%D7%94%D7%A9%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%90%D7%97%D7%A8%D7%99-%D7%92%D7%90%D7%99%D7%9A-morning-activities-before-prayers)

Comment: relevant: https://www.halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Other_Activities_before_Davening - https://ph.yhb.org.il/en/category/tefila/12-before-the-shacharit-prayer/ - https://www.yeshiva.co/midrash/28269

Comment: Welcome to MiYodeya and thanks for this first question. Please don't use the text of the question for comments, they belong below the question just as you did already. Since MY is different from other sites you might be used to, see [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) for a guide which might help understand the site. Great to have you learn with us!

Comment: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/111010/why-is-greeting-someone-before-praying-compared-to-building-a-private-altar#comment373099_111010